# iOS: pass gesture to views underneath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a simple setup: there are 2 sibling `UIViews` A and B, B fully covers A (but it is transparent, so A is visible):

```
┌──────────────────┐
│   View A         │
│                  │
│   ┌──────────────┴───┐
│   │   View B         │
│   │                  │
│   │                  │
│   │                  │
│   │                  │
│   │                  │
└───┤                  │
    │                  │
    │                  │
    └──────────────────┘
```

I need 2 different `UIGestureRecognizers`: A should have a tap recognizer and B should have a pan recognizer. Whenever I tap on B it should pass the touch events to view A behind so that it can recognize a tap (I will use some logic to understand if pan was accepted or not, like distance, start area, etc). Is this possible to do in iOS?

My experience so far is that once B accepts a touch it will never forward it to A which is behind. And the decision to accept or not should be done immediately in overriden `pointInside` or `hitTest` functions. However, in my case the decision is based on some logic and depends on the context and history of user interaction.

Comment: As per responder chain it will forwards the event to next view (or next level), if it is not handled by the top object, but if it is handled by top object then it won't pass that to next level. So in your case if view B is responding the touch event it will not pass the touch to view A, but yes if you forcefully block the touch event in view B, then the responder chain passes the touch event to view A. hope it helps

Comment: I've a similar situation. And tried many things but does not seem to work. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If B covers A, it's going to prevent A from receiving gestures. But why do you have this transparent B over A? Get rid of B and put both gestures on A. And then you can define the tap gesture to require the pan gesture to fail.

Comment: I guess that is what I will do in the end. In my case A is a complex view with bunch of views, images, buttons which have several swipe, tap, double tap recognizers on them. I just wanted to add a pan feature over all the views (like drawing a hint with a finger starting in a specific area does something cool) and didn't wanted to mess with the existing layout. So I thought to add a view above all and do my stuff in it. But then it steals everything and events don't reach to the views below.

Comment: Let's not overprescribe by telling frangulyan how to modify the app. View A may need to be there as a guide, or it could be essential to the rest of the program. Assume that OP has her reasons, and just answer the question!

Comment: I respectfully disagree. It would be a great disservice to fail to point out that rather than contorting one’s self with this invisible view, one should consider whether this view is needed at all.  And look at the OP’s comment: It outlines a scenario where the invisible view is completely unnecessary.

Comment: In my case, the B view holds view from 5 different controllers. And these 5 controllers further contains views which has gestures applied to them. And I want a common gesture on every of these 5 controller views. So yes A view is necessary. Any solution you could give?

Answer (score 1):

As per `Responder Chain` it will forwards the event to next view (or next level), if it is not handled by the top object, but if it is handled by top object then it won't pass that to next level. So in your case if view B is responding the touch event it will not pass the touch to view A, but yes if you forcefully block the touch event in view B, then the `Responder Chain` passes the touch event to view A.

More is here in the link : [enter link description here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html)

hope it helps

Comment: You're right, but, as I wrote, in my case I cannot block touch in B right away. I need to wait a bit, get a bunch of touches, understand that it is not a pan that I need and say "ok, I don't need this, pass it to A". iOS does this all in case of gesture recognizers added to the same view: they work simultaneously, they require some others to fail in order to succeed, and so on. I guess this cannot be done in case of gesture recognizers attached to 2 different overlapping views.

Answer (score 0):

i found this one add this class to top view

```
@interface ClickthroughView : UIView
@end

@implementation ClickthroughView
-(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    return NO;
}
@end
```

Comment: But in this case ClickthroughView will not get any touches at all, which is not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Tap recognizer to both A and B. Then you can disambiguate the Tap and the Pan within B using whatever logic you need. Your Tap handler can use the gesture.view to see whether it came from A or B, and convert the touch to A coordinates in either case.